# void' should be preceded by ';' error?

Tags: visual-c++

So I'm using Visual studio C++. My current program was so create an array in reverse...but I'm getting the error of "void' should be preceded by ';'". Help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

//this function outputs the array in reverse
void reverse(double* a, int size)
{

for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; --i)//either i=size or i=size-1
{
cout << a[i] << ' ';
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You are missing an opening { after `int main()`.

So your code would be

```
int main()
{
//this function outputs the array in reverse
void reverse(double* a, int size)
```

However, there are other errors. For one, your main does not return a value. And your program should be structured differently. It should be

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//this function outputs the array in reverse
void reverse(double* a, int size)
{
    for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; --i)//either i=size or i=size-1
    {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Some of these errors are easily noticable by formatting your code. Since you are using Visual Studio, the default to do this is Ctrl+K and Ctrl+ D.

Comment: Can the downvoter comment as to why?